# How to generate dynamic buttons inside a canvas in Windows Phone 8.1 from viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app

EDIT: As becuase there are too many suggestions I got, so firstly I consider to change it step by step, so my first problem is to get the dynamic Buttons from ViewModel to View.

I am writing a WP 8.1 Game apps. So from `MainPage.xaml` my game navigate to `GamePage.xaml`. in the `OnNavigatedTo` method I have a code like this.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Initialize GamePageViewModel
    gmPageViewModel = new GamePageViewModel(this);
    this.DataContext = gmPageViewModel;
}
```

Firstly in the View I have set the DataContext for the Grid I set the DataContext as

```
<Grid 
   DataContext="{Binding GamePageVM, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" >
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Moves, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
<Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Grid.Row="2" 
                DataContext="{Binding ButtonItems, 
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                              Mode=TwoWay}">
<ItemsControl >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <Canvas />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding TopLeftX}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding TopLeftY}"/>
     </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Width="{Binding Width}" 
         Height="{Binding Height}" 
         Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding Content, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</Grid>
```

So this is my View, Now I generate some random Buttons based on certain game label, it can be 5 it can be 15 but the condition is buttons should not overlap each others. 
So in the  ViewModel I have a property called `ButtonItems` which bind to Canvas `DataContext`, "Value" and "Moves" Binding to two TextBlocks as in the code.

The ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ButtonPosition> ButtonItems{...}
public string Moves{...}
public string Value {...}
public GamePageViewModel GamePageViewModels{...}

public GamePageViewModel()
        {
            initTheBoard();
            _moves= GameObject.Moves.ToString();
            _value = GameObject.Value.ToString();
        }
```

GameObject is an Object which generates some unique random numbers.

Now this InItBoard() where I create dynamic buttons `ButtonItems`

```
    private void initTheBoard()
    {
      buttonItems = new ObservableCollection<ButtonPosition>();
      Random r = new Random();
      List<ButtonPosition> buttonPositions = new List<ButtonPosition>();
      Button button;

      for (int i = 0; i < numOfButtons; i++)
      {
         button = new Button();
         bool foundOverlap = false;
         int left;
         int top;
         ButtonPosition bp;
         do
         {
            foundOverlap = false;
            // Create a new random position for the button (subtracting the width/height 
            // from the X,Y so that we don't overlap the edge of the canvas)
         left = r.Next(0, 500 - buttonWidth - 10);
         top = r.Next(0, 500 - buttonHeight - 10);
         bp = new ButtonPosition(left, top, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
         // Check each of the existing buttons for overlap
         foreach (ButtonPosition existingButton in buttonPositions)
         {
            if (bp.Overlaps(existingButton))
            {
               foundOverlap = true;
               break;
            }
         }
        } while (foundOverlap);

    buttonItems.Add(bp);
    buttonPositions.Add(bp);
   }
 }

 gamePageVM = this;
```

So in this way I populate the viewModel, but View doesn't display any of the buttons that are created dynamically. I found that in Windows Phone 8.1 `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>` doesn't give any result, so I remove that and I put 
`Canvas.Left="{Binding TopLeftX}"
Canvas.Top="{Binding TopLeftY}"` in the `<DataTemplate>` but no result.

One more thing ButtonsPositions is one more class which is having the logic of checking if any button is overlapping with any other buttons, its having two property TopLeftX, TopLeftY, which is Biding to XAML.

```
public class ButtonsPositions
 {
    public int TopLeftX { get; set; }
    public int TopLeftY { get; set; }
    public int Width {get; set;}
    public int Height{get; set;}
 }
```

This Height, Width, TopLeftX and TopLeftY is bound to Datatemplate of the button.
Any help, why the Buttons are not getting loaded into the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of time and after trying many options finally I found the problem, let me tell you what's the problem is ...

In WPF

```
   <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=TopLeftX}" />       
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Path=TopLeftY}" />
      </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

This works perfectly, but for WPF, n silverlight, in Windows Phone 8.1 or WinRT this does not work, if you set Value="50" - some fixed value it does work, but any `DataBinding` it sets the value to `0,0` and put the items in the `0,0` th location in the canvas.

So in WinRT it does not work in that way, and after a lot of research and search I found a solution. It lies in the `DataTemplate`
if we use

```
<Button.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
       <TranslateTransform X="{Binding TopLeftX}" Y="{Binding TopLeftY}" />
       </TransformGroup>
</Button.RenderTransform>
```

And one more change we need to make.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=TopLeftX}" />
      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"  Value="{Binding Path=TopLeftY}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Instead of `ContentPresenter` we have to use `FrameworkElement` for Silverlight

And this is the solution I wanted. And it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is replace `GamePage` object inside of your view model, then add a method to your view model that accepts a `GamePage`.

```
public void ReplaceGamePage(GamePage page)
{
     this.GamePage = page;
}
```

If the GamePage property on the view model has Property Changed eventing wired up, your view will be refreshed. Another way is to just force a refresh of the data context on the view. In your code-behind click event handler, you can raise the on property changed event.

```
this.OnPropertyChanged(new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(this.DataContext, this.DataContext, new GamePage()));
```

This will refresh the DataContext binding, forcing the view to update all of its bindings with the view model.

I'd strongly recommend however that you stop mixing view specific stuff in to your view model. MVVM is a one-way road. View Models should not know of view elements, only present data for the view to bind to.

What you should do is hide your buttons behind a model, give each model a random X/Y location and then bind the collection of models to an ItemsControl on the view. You can assign a DataTemplate for the model, rendering each model as a button, at the X/Y value defined in the model. That would let you wire up commanding then to your view model and remove the need for code-behind.

Comment: `ReplaceGamePage` will be in a viewModel and accepts parameter GamePage, but in my ViewModel there is no property for `gamepage`, and the `click_event` handler is not in a Code behind its in a viewModel. DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(this.DataContext, this.DataContext, new GamePage())) is giving error that it's constructor doesn't contain three arguments

Comment: Thanks for the Button - Model suggestions will try that, the problem is button numbers I choose randomly based on the game label. So was facing difficulty and the main focus is to dynamically refresh the game page and add some animations in to the canvas and when the user click on the buttons

Comment: You should not be passing your view in to your view model at all. The ViewModel should not know that the view instance exists.

Comment: If you use the MVVM pattern, you can achieve this without giving the view model your view reference. The view model can still assign random numbers to the models based off of a _string property_ that the label is data-bound to. Do not have a `Label` reference in your view model. Add a label to the view, bind it to a string property on the view model, and let the view model generate numbers for the models based on the string property. Your view can then create buttons from a collection of the models, via templating, as mentionedin my answer.

Comment: I have updated my question, I think if I can mange to populate the View from ViewModel as you suggested I can get the refresh UI functionality, But still I am unable to get it working, I have posted the entire code possible. Can you please find out what's the mistake?

Comment: My answer is to not generate the buttons in the view model. I've explained how you should solve this already.

Comment: can you please give some example, in this examples I have ObservableCollections<ButtonPositions> that's bound to the Canvas dataContext. and this buttonPositions have X-Y coordinates. that's the DataTemplate of the ItemTemplate,